# Leanback version of AlertDialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, leanback

In Android, making an `AlertDialog` with `Positive/Negative` buttons is easy.

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
           .setTitle("Question?")
           .setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               @Override
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                   // User chose YES
               }
           })
           .setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               @Override
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                   // User chose NO
                }
           }).create().show();
```

I would like to make the equivalent in my **TV App**. (ask the user a question, get the Yes/No response)

I have found two things, neither of which solve my use case:

1. ErrorFragment (close, but only has 1 button)
2. GuidedStepFragment (allows me multiple options, but requires creating a separate Activity, and I have to write my own code to pass the selected choice back to the first Activity)

I feel like i'm missing something. This is only a few lines of code in a normal Android app.

I tried just using `AlertDialog` in my TV App, but it throws an error about having the incorrect `Theme` set on the App. Plus, I don't think those dialogs are accesibility friendly anyway.

Answer (score 9):

Looks like this is possible by adding a Theme to the AlertDialog call:

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity(), R.style.Theme_AppCompat)
   ....
```

Comment: It makes the alert dialog full screen and kinda fugly. Any ideas?

Comment: @Sealer_05 pass R.style.Theme_AppCompat_Dialog_Alert or other suitable dialog style to make it smaller.

Comment: R.style.Theme_AppCompat_Dialog_Alert works fine for me

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to show an `AlertDialog` without throwing an error then you can construct the `AlertDialog.Builder` with a theme,
I prefer using `AlertDialog.THEME_DEVICE_DEFAULT_DARK`

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity(), AlertDialog.THEME_DEVICE_DEFAULT_DARK)
       .setTitle("Question?")
       .setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
               // User chose YES
           }
       })
       .setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
               // User chose NO
            }
       }).create().show();
```

I can't help you if you want to build an `AlertDialog` that looks like an `ErrorFragment` or a `GuidedStepFragment`

### Edit:

`AlertDialog.THEME_DEVICE_DEFAULT_DARK` was deprecated in API level 23, so you can use `android.R.style.Theme_DeviceDefault_Dialog_Alert` instead, like this:

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity(), android.R.style.Theme_DeviceDefault_Dialog_Alert)
       .setTitle("Question?")
       .setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
               // User chose YES
           }
       })
       .setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
               // User chose NO
            }
       }).create().show();
```

Comment: Cannot resolve symbol 'THEME_DEVICE_DEFAULT_DARK'. Where does it come from?

Comment: See the edit that i've done to this post.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can use a class called `TvDialog`, which uses `GuidedStepFragment` to create something like this:

[image]

You can see it [here](https://peirr.com/android-tv-dialog/)